# Pinia: Cannot access store from Nuxt3 API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

I have a Nuxt3 project with an Api in `server/api/<api-endpoints>`. Inside an endpoint, when I try to  use a Pinia Store it says:

`[nuxt] [request error] []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?`

or when I try to access a composable function from `composables` it cannot define any variable (says xxx is undefined even though it works in components so it just can't define anything in the function).

Pinia example inside `server/api/token`

```
import { useAuthStore } from "../stores/useAuthStore";
export default async (req: any, res: any) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore()
    return authStore.access_token
};
```

Composable example inside `server/api/user`

```
import { useUserLogin } from "../../composables/useUserLogin";
export default async (req: any, res: any) => {
    const userLogin = useUserLogin()
    return twitchLogin.is_logged_in
};
```

Comment: How did you installed Pinia?

Comment: @kissu via `npm install @pinia/nuxt`. So my goal is the following: I want to be able to POST to eg. `http://localhost:3000/api/login` with an access_token in the body, then in the endpoint function update the state (Pinia) via `authStore.access_token = req.body.access_token` and then run `authStore.loginUser()`. So I want to post to the server to change Pinia states and run functions from other files/composables. But it seems like the Nuxt server is somehow disconnected from the Nuxt project itself.

Comment: Did you also added it to your `buildModules` as shown here: https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#installation ?

Comment: @kissu Yes, I did add it. I can access the stores inside my components and inside composables but not anywhere else. Vice versa with the composables.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by renaming **buildModules** to **modules** in nuxt.config.js

> Nuxt **modules** are now build-time-only, and the **buildModules** property
> used in Nuxt 2 is deprecated in favor of modules.

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    // ...
    '@pinia/nuxt',
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue trying to do something similar. When I ran `nuxi dev` `const authStore = useAuthStore()` will run. However when you `nuxi build` and run the output you will encounter the same error.

Since this is happening outside of setup I had to pass the $pinia context to the useStore. (Documented here https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#using-the-store-outside-of-setup)

i.e.

```
import { useAuthStore } from "../stores/useAuthStore";
export default async (req: any, res: any) => {
    const { $pinia } = useNuxtApp()
    const authStore = useAuthStore($pinia)
    return authStore.access_token
};
```